# How to distinguish child dependencies in parent pom?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have several child pom.xml file which have same dependency, but 
they differ only version. I want to use `<dependencyManagement>` for inherit them from parent pom.xml. Example:

```
   Child1:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>

   Child2:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.9</version>
</dependency>

   Child3:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any way to distinguish them or just leave it like it is?

Comment: Did a double take on child pom.xml

Comment: I'm newbie with Maven, could you said more about it? Maybe some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use `dependencyManagement` to declare these dependencies in the parent POM and then inherit that declaration and override its version in the child POM.

So given the example in your question, if the parent POM looks like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then your child POMs can still declare their own version of `com.google.code.gson:gson`.

**But** ... the canonical benefits of using `dependencyManagement` are ...

> The Dependency Management provides:
>
> - Consolidate and centralize the management of versions ... this is particularly useful when you have multiple projects with a shared parent
> - Define a standard version of an artifact to be used on multiple projects

... and this approach of declaring a dependency including a version in a child POM renders the `dependencyManagement` declaration in the parent POM irrelevant i.e. why bother declaring it if you then choose to override every aspect of that declration.

In summary; use `dependencyManagement` if you have a dependency which is used in more than one child module and for which you want to define a common version. If a dependency is only used in one sub module and/or you do not want to insist on a single version of that dependency being used across all child modules then don't bother creating a `dependencyManagement` entry for that dependency.